# render json: scoped subresources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Previously I was successfully rendering a Customer resource, including it's nested Discount resources using the below code:

```
class Discount < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
end

format.json { render json: Customer.find(params[:id]), :include => { :discounts =>
  {:include => {...}
  }}
}}
```

I later added a scope to my Discount i.e.

```
class Discount < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer

  scope :current, where('(begin_on <= ? OR begin_on IS NULL) AND (? <= end_on OR end_on IS NULL)', Date.today, Date.today)
end
```

How can I make the above json call render only these current discounts rather than all Customer.discounts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I've come up with a solution. I'd be interested in any alternative answers, but for my purposes this seems to work:

```
format.json { render json: @customer, :methods => [:current_discounts]}

class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :discounts

  def current_discounts
    discounts.current
  end
end
```